# Global variable on NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm using NGINX to serve static files, reverse proxy to Django and verify client certificates.

I don't want the certificate to be asked at the url root, so I created another server on Nginx.conf to ask for the certificate on port 8443. This server is intended just to ask for the certificate and redirect the client back to port 443, where the reverse proxy to Django occurs.

This is my Nginx.conf:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on; 

    upstream app {
        server django:8000;
    }

    # Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS
    server {
        listen *:80;
        server_name localhost;
        return 301 https://localhost$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        
        listen *:443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.key;
        ssl_password_file    /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.pass;

        ssl_verify_client off;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/chain.cer;
        ssl_verify_depth 3;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;                
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        server_tokens off;
        underscores_in_headers on;

        location /static/ {
            autoindex off;
            alias /static_files/;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @app_web;
        }

        location @app_web {
            proxy_pass http://app;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header CERTINFO $http_certinfo;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }

    server {
        
        listen *:8443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.key;
        ssl_password_file    /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.pass;

        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certificate.cer
        ssl_verify_depth 3;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;                
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        add_header CERTINFO $ssl_client_s_dn;

        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    
    }
}
```

When the client authenticates on port 8443 and I return him to port 443, I need to forward his certificate information, the [$ssl_client_s_dn](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#variables) to be more specific. To do so, I'm trying to use the method add_header on the server of the port 8443 (CERTINFO) and the method proxy_set_header capturing the value with $http_certinfo on the server of the port 443. But this solution is not working. The header is not forwarded from port 8443 to port 443 server.

My question is: is there a way to do that? Can I set some kind of "global" variable on the http block, change its value on port 8443 and than use the updated value on port 443 to forward it to Django?

Thank you so much!

Comment: No. `add_header` adds a response header and `$http_certinfo` is a request header. You can't make the browser add another request header except perhaps a cookie.

Comment: Ricardo, but is there a way to store this information not in a request header, but in some kind of variable, and share it with the other server? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Instead of the `return 301` you should duplicate the `location` blocks from the first `server` block so this `server` block can pass the credentials directly to the app.

Comment: Your solution works just fine, Richard. I passed the credentials directly to the app and redirected the client back to the port 443 through the app as well. Thank you for your help.